# regex to find numbers occurring before month names (pandas)

Tags: regex, pandas

I am trying to extract the digits before a month name, in a pandas column, if the digits and month name are there.  The strings in the column look like this:

```
133    h missed intake office visit on 28 June 1994 a...
136    11 February 1985 CPT Code: 90801 - Psychiatric...
150                  12 March 1980 SOS-10 Total Score:\n
151                      22 June 1990 Medical History:\n
165    .On 18 August 1975 patient presented to BH ED/...
181                18 August 1995 Primary Care Doctor:\n
182    eby 13 June 1974 it appears amitriptyline had ...
188    12 March 2004 CPT Code: 90801 - Psychiatric Di...
228    s 20 yo M carries dx of BPAD, presents for psy...
229    t Allergies Sulfa (Sulfonamide Antibiotics) - ...
230    B/R Walnut Ridge. Raised with sister and paren...
231    50 yo DWF with a history of alcohol use disord...
232    )HTN, hypercholesterolemia, DM, sleep apnea,, ...
```

So for example on the rows 133 I would be looking to get the 28 out from before the word June, and on the row 136, the 11 from before the word February.

I am trying to adapt a previously used regex to get the numbers.  This regex is:

```
DF["col2"] = DF["col1"].str.extract(r'\b\d{1,2}\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July)|August|September|October|November|December')
```

I guess the capturing parentheses are causing the object to be extracted to be the month and not the digits, but when I try to place capturing parenthesis on the digits `\d{1,2}` I receive an error.

How would I obtain the digits only, from this column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only extract days numeric part before month names, you may use

```
r'\b(\d{1,2})\s(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)
    ^       ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypwjZZ/1/).

The capturing parentheses are around the `\d{1,2}` pattern part only.  The month names are inside a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) that does not create a separate capture.

Note also that the month names are all placed into a grouping construct, in the original regex, the ending `)` was placed after `July` and ruins the regex.

Comment: Standing on the shoulders of giants.  THANK YOU.